# Transform Javascript sorting column in a table function to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay, this is my current table:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGm4E.png)

My current Javascript function lets me sort the column alphabetically asc or desc when I click the name of the th.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('th').each(function(col) {
            $(this).hover(
            function() { $(this).toggleClass('focus'); }
        );

            $(this).click(function() {
                if ($(this).is('.asc')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('asc');
                    $(this).addClass('desc seleccionado');
                    orden = -1;
                }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass('asc seleccionado');
                    $(this).removeClass('desc');
                    orden = 1;
                }

                $(this).siblings().removeClass('asc seleccionado');
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('desc seleccionado');
                var arrData = $('table').find('tbody >tr:has(td)').get();
                arrData.sort(function(a, b) {
                    var valor1 = $(a).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
                    var valor2 = $(b).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
                    if($.isNumeric(valor1) && $.isNumeric(valor2)) {
                        return orden == 1 ? valor1-valor2 : valor2-valor1;
                    }
                    else {
                        return (valor1 < valor2) ? -orden : (valor1 > valor2) ? orden : 0;
                    }
                });
                $.each(arrData, function(index, row) {
                    $('tbody').append(row);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

I need to not use Javascript to do this but instead use AJAX, I tried a couple of examples from Internet but none of worked. Also I can't use plugins, like jQuery Datatables.

Comment: By AJAX, do you mean sorting server-side?   This post may help you:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651387/how-to-apply-sorting-and-filtering-using-ajax-json-php-mysql

Comment: Yes, but the link you provided did not help me, I tried implementing what Gavin said but did not work, any other suggestion?